# Switching from one image to another

Tags: html, image, timing

I'm trying to figure out how to switch from one image to another after 500 ms. What I have currently keeps switching between images, but I want each image to display for 500 ms and to have the second image disappear after that 500 ms instead of having it loop. This is what I have right now:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>loop</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">

function displayNextImage() {
x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
}

function displayPreviousImage() {
x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
}
function startTimer() {
setInterval(displayNextImage, 500);
}

var images = [], x = -1;
images[0] = "image1.jpg";
images[1] = "image2.jpg";
</script>
</head>
</html>
<body onload = "startTimer()">
<img id="img" src="image1.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me fix this? Thank you!

Comment: please rephrase your question. you are not asking how to switch images, but asking how to do X in an interval. where X is "photo change" (in your very specific case)

Comment: Why don't you do this with CSS animations?

Comment: @Siyah - that's not the point. it's not about CSS or images, it's about his javascript doesn't work.

Comment: 1. nowhere you initially define that `x=0` so why would `x + 1` even work.. and 2. don't use globals...

Comment: That, I do know. I am just asking a question :)

Comment: Yes, i'm just looking to switch from one image to the next after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Well did you understand my comment? you didn't respond to it. have you tried declaring the variable as `0` first?

Comment: Yes; that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want it to do:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>loop</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">

    var images = [];
    var x = 0;
    var $img = document.getElementById("img");

    images[0] = "image1.jpg";
    images[1] = "image2.jpg";

    function displayNextImage() {
        if (++x < images.length) {
            $img.src = images[x];
            setInterval(displayNextImage, 500);
        }
        else {
            $img.remove();
        }
    }

    function startTimer() {
        setInterval(displayNextImage, 500);
    }


</script>
</head>
</html>
<body onload = "startTimer()">
<img id="img" src="image1.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @eesther: Try it now - I had a logic error in my `if` statement.

Comment: Does this use jquery?  It seems to only work when I put it in the html and javascript sections and preview it, but if I run it on the site, it doesn't work.  I wonder if it's because the site i'm running it on uses the prototype javascript framework.